# Memory (and large project) management

Tags: linked-data, groups, memory-management

From what I've understood from other questions here, group instancing and dynamic linking are two methods for managing memory in a project that is large or complex. The latter also allows one to divide a project into many different components, to better work on each separate component and easily update any changes in the main project file.

This is where I have additional questions.

Let's suppose we are creating an office, with each floor being complete with furniture in varying amounts, types and locations per floor. Each model would be highly detailed, and therefore memory intensive. **What would be the most effective way to approach this project as far as memory consumption is concerned?**

To my understanding, two possible methods would be to create a group instance for each type of furniture and add them as needed, or use dynamic linking. With group instancing, if there are hundreds of pieces of furniture, but only a variety of five or ten, then the memory consumption should not go too much higher than what would be required for five or ten models (as opposed to hundreds).

What is unclear to me is how linking external files work in terms of memory management. Firstly, I am making the assumption that the 'Link' function (Ctrl+Alt+O) under 'File' is what people talk about when they refer to dynamic linking. Now there is already an issue when linking. When selecting the .blend file and linking the data in the 'Object' directory, the object appears in the center of the project and cannot be moved. The solution here appears to be the 'Make Proxy' command. **When this command is used and the object is translated, rotated, scaled, or otherwise manipulated in any way, what happens to memory consumption?**

At this point, we would have one linked object in the main project. **To add additional objects of the same type, would you keep linking the same external file multiple times until the desired quantity is reached, or is there a better option?**

Now suppose you wanted to animate one of these objects. Using the office example, say one chair could be reclined. **Can bones be added to the mesh and have it all animated, without affecting other objects linked from the same file?** This doesn't seem possible with group instancing from what I've tried doing. Editing the object in the group results in a change to every instance of the group. Assuming dynamic linking can achieve manageable duplicates of objects, **would it be possible to link an object, then create the armature/bones and animation in the main project file? Is there a better, more organised solution?**

Comment: Don't link objects, link groups. Have a rig effecting the item be part of the group. Copy linked groups with Alt D, no need to link them multiple times. Create a proxy rig from the linked groups on the groups you want to animate/change (Ctrl Alt P). This proxy rig will effect only the one instance.

Comment: @Jerryno is memory supposed to still increase significantly?

Comment: No, memory should increase but not significantly. Linking dupli-groups is as memory efficient as it can get.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need as separate posts. I see 5 questions, which should probably be separated into at least 3 different posts. I suggest editing this questions using the [edit] link below it down to just 1 question and asking the others separately.

Comment: I would if there wasn't a time limit on questions.

Comment: Nevertheless, that is how this site works. One question per post.

Comment: @Jerryno How do I link everything within another file? I can't seem to be able to link a group without their materials.